# Shared element transition from fragment to recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-transitions, android-architecture-navigation

I have on question. I am being trying to implement shared element transition from fragment to recycler view or from recycler view to recycler view it but it's not working. I am using Jetpack navigation component.

**The case where it works**

> when I use shared element transition from recycler view to fragment.

But I am trying to work it out for recycler view to recycler view. Is it possible to do so? I have tried postponing enter transition i.e. after the recycler item is ready to be populated start the enter transition but unfortunately it does not work as well.

Comment: did you check this https://link.medium.com/OAyPMKy9TW

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Yes I did checked the blog before. But it seems it has something to do with Recycler view to recycler view shared element & not navigation component.